# PowerShell, git pull if present, or git clone if not

Tags: git, powershell, git-clone, git-pull

I saw this construct on a question about bash

```
git -C 'repo-path' pull || git clone https://server/repo-name 'repo-path'
```

So, if the `git pull` fails, then do the `git clone`, which seems quite a clean approach.

What would be an equivalent syntax for this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that syntax would work as expected on PowerShell core, since it now supports || and &&.

If you need this to work on pre-PowerShell core systems, you could use `$lastExitCode` to determine if the previous step worked or not.

```
git -C 'repo-path' pull
# If the previous line worked, lastExitCode will be zero
if ($lastexitCode) {  
   git clone https://server/repo-name 'repo-path'
}
```

Comment: For my needs, I need something in PS 5.1, is there a way to get similar syntax on older PowerShell? (it is also very interesting that this works unchanged on PS 7.x though!).

Comment: Updated the answer to include how you'd do things on 5.1

Comment: Sadly, I see it's a bit more verbose in 5.1. I thought there might be an equivalently simple one-liner (sure, I can concatenate all of this onto one line with `;`, but not quite as clean as the bash / PS 7.x way. I'll use your method in 5.1 though, many thanks.